# Create textfield and button programmatically click button get textfield text

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 200, 30);
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;

UIButton *but= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[but addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[but setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 80, 215, 40)];
[but setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[but setExclusiveTouch:YES];

[view addSubview:but];
[view addSubview:textField];
[view addSubview:label];
```

I created textfield and button when i clicked button i want to get textfield text in buttonClicked function

```
-(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
    // I want to get textfield text right here
}
```

Comment: Using tag is good option. assign tag for both and then get value as per tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give `tag` to your `UITextField` following way..

```
[textfiled setTag:101];
```

then get text by following way.

```
-(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
    UITextField * textField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:101];
    NSLog(@"your text = %@",textField.text);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the textfield declaration in the .h file and then access it without any problems.

Then, when you add textfield to the same as you did before.

In button click you can call that textbox via `self.textbox`.

The other way to do this ( if you really want to keep this chunk of code ) would be to create UIView and then on click get superview of the button, go through elements in ui view and find UITextField. I wouldn't recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

in your viewController.h file assign

```
UITextField *textField;
```

and in ViewConroller.m file do like this

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 200, 30);
textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
...
```

Then you can get text value by

```
textField.text
```

also you can do as by @AbhishekSharma

Comment: One correction, you will use it as _textField or self.textField

Comment: no you can use directly. because I don't set the property for textField. So you can use directly, no need to put _ .@NickCatib